# How to sum a row of integers from a file that contains multiple rows - Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nested-loops

I am trying to sum numbers in separate lines from a file. In addition, I would like the code to ignore the first number of every line.

```
3 3 3 3
1 1 1 1 1
2 2
```

From these numbers I would like to print out 9, 4 and 2.

Whereas I am getting an answer of 21 as I sum everything apparently with this amateur piece of code:

```
  while(scan.hasNextInt())  
    {  
        a = a + scan.nextInt();
    } 
    System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("D:\\data.txt"));
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] numbers = line.split("\\s");
        int result = 0;
        for(int i=1 ; i<numbers.length ; i++) {
            result = result + Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Line "+line+"  : result "+ result);
    }
}
```

**result**

```
Line 3 3 3 3  : result 9
Line 1 1 1 1 1  : result 4
Line 2 2   : result 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    String input = "3 3 3 3\n1 1 1 1 1\n2 2";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(input); 
    while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
        Scanner line = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());
        int calculation = 0;
        for(int i = 0;line.hasNextInt();i++) {
            if(i>0) {
                calculation = calculation+line.nextInt();
            }else {
                line.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(calculation);
    }
```

I was able to get your required output using scanners instead of an array to save the lines if the input is from the console or `System.in` youll have to account for that in the `scan` variable

Answer (score 1):

Without your other side of codes but I think i understood what you'r trying to do.

So you can take all the line by line and can start from second object.Her is the code:

```
        String line;
        while((line = scan.nextLine() != null)) {
            String[] lines = line.split(" ");
            int total = 0;
            for(int i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
                total += Integer.parseInt(lines[i]);
            }
            
            System.out.println(total);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

And for completeness, a stream solution.

```
try {
    // read in the lines and stream them
    Files.lines(Path.of("f:/source.txt"))

    // split the lines on spaces and stream the tokens
            .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+"))

    // skip the first one
                    .skip(1)
    // convert each token to an int
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    // sum them
                    .sum())
    // and print each sum
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    // catch and print any exceptions.
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a 1-liner:

```
Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("D:/data.txt")).stream()
.map(line -> line.split(" "))
.map(Arrays::stream)
.mapToInt(stream -> stream.skip(1).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt),sum())
.forEach(System.out::println);
```